# Status of all the major houses and kingdoms at the end of Game of Thrones

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

We see the end of Game of Thrones now but I want to know the status of all the major houses and kingdoms in the end.

We know Sansa is ruling the north as a free kingdom, Yara Greyjoy is ruling the Iron Islands, and Bran is the king of the six kingdoms but what about the rest?

Comment: In short: f—ed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Six Kingdoms

**Kingdom of Mountain and Vale - House Arryn**
Ruler: Robyn Arryn; The Vale is a part of the six kingdoms

**Kingdom of the Reach - Unknown**
Ruler: Bronn; Highgarden is part of the six kingdoms; Bronn was given highgarden as payment of the Lannister debts.

**Kingdom of the Stormlands - House Baratheon**
Ruler: Gendry Baratheon; The Stormlands are a part of the six kingdoms

**Principality of Dorne - Unknown**
Prince of Dorne; Dorne is a part of the six kingdoms

**Kingdom of the Rock - House Lannister**
Ruler: Lord Tyrion Lannister; the Westerlands are a part of the six kingdoms; Tyrion is the hand of the king.

**Kingdom of Isles and Rivers - House Tully**
Ruler: Edmure Tully; The Riverlands are a part of the six kingdoms

**Iron Islands - on/off part of Riverrun - House Greyjoy**
Ruler: Yara Greyjoy; The Iron Islands have been a part of the Kingdom of Isles and Rivers on and off but mostly independent throughout history.

### The North

**Kingdom of the North - House Stark**
Ruler: Sansa Stark; Independent kingdom of its own with almost all of the north pledging their allegiance to Winterfell

### Other Major Houses

House Targaryen - Undecided with Jon out in the wild and the 7 kingdoms not yet knowing his true parentage.

House Tarly - Ruler: Samwell Tarly; Hornhill (The Reach) is sworn to Highgarden; from S8E6 voting scene, it's clear that Sam is in charge of Hornhill.

### Extinct Houses

House Clegane,
House Tyrell,
House Martell,
House Bolton,
House Mormont,
House Karstark,
House Blackfyre,
House Umber,
House Frey

Comment: I don't think the Reach is House Tyrell anymore, unless Bronn has simply been declared a Tyrell to keep things easy.  Tyrion didn't address him with any sort of house name in the small council meeting.  Kind of remarkable that Tyrell is the only ruling house to have lost control.

Comment: Do we know that house Martell is truly extinct? For all we know, this new unnamed Prince of Dorne may be from the wider Martell family.

Comment: Lot of official sources show that the Martell lineage has ended - and that we are not sure about the current rulers of Dorne

Comment: Another option is that The Reach is now ruled from Oldtown by House Hightower. Bronn was only promised Highgarden, neither the titles Lord Paramount nor Warden.

Comment: Certainly the ruling house of Dorne isn't called Dorne.

Comment: Tyrion isn't the last Lannister. The Lannisters of Lannisport still presumably exist.

Comment: Sam is a Maester. Can a Maester hold lands?

Comment: Im not really sure about Sam, because if he was still a maester, he wouldnt have the power to vote.

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill He might keep "Stokeworth" as his house

Comment: If anyone sees any mistakes in my answer, please do feel free to make the edits.. I tried to gather as much as I could and yet some info is wrong..  so I would appreciate all of your inputs going into the answer.. I may not be able to make changes immediately.

Comment: @OrangeDog He may not have been *promised* the Lord Paramount title, but his new title, spoken at the Small Council meeting, is "Ser Bronn of the Blackwater, Lord of Highgarden, *Lord Paramount of the Reach*, and Master of Coin"